# Embed xsl:value-of into onload in xslt stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to have a `xsl:value-of` concat with a `xsl:variable` inside the `img`.

```
<xsl:variable name="tail" select="'@domain.com'"/>
<SPAN id="ProfileViewer_Name">
    <img border="0" width="12" height="12" src="http://domain/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" alt="" onload="QueuePopulateIMNRC('<xsl:value-of select="Initials"/>{$tail}', this);" name="imnmark" ShowOfflinePawn="1" id="user_ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl03_im,type=sip" />
</SPAN>
```

I can place the value-of outside the img tag and it pulls the values just fine. I'm pretty sure it's a matter of nesting quotations, but I've tried quite a few permutations and nothing has worked yet.

The expected input would be having the lines initials in the onload. Instead, it seems to pull one initial at random and insert it for each output. If I have the xsl:value-of outside the img tag I get the correct values, but once it's embed it seems to fail. So I get something along the lines of

XXXX@
XXXX@
XXXX@

Where I need something like

AAAA@
BBBB@
CCCC@

Comment: You should provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using an attribute value template, so it's the same mechanism:

```
<xsl:variable name="tail" select="'@domain.com'"/>
<SPAN id="ProfileViewer_Name">
    <img border="0" width="12" height="12" src="http://domain/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" alt="" onload="QueuePopulateIMNRC('{Initials}{$tail}', this);" name="imnmark" ShowOfflinePawn="1" id="user_ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl03_im,type=sip" />
</SPAN>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not pulling unique fields, it's grabbing one value and inserting it for each item.

Comment: Then your input isn't what I guessed it was. Next time, don't make me guess.